# Any way to do transparent API for next.js?

Tags: next.js

Next.JS simplifies lots of stuff for creating the Web App. But the modelling data and the API and the data communication between the Server and the Client stays pretty much the same as in other React.JS apps.

A lot of code needed to be written to make it possible. I wonder if there's some approach or extension for Next.JS that would make it easier? Something like meteor or like that?

Answer (score 0):

Realise this is an old question, but take a look at [Blitz JS](https://blitzjs.com) - this wasn't around at the time the question was asked, but has been [one of 2020's top projects on Github](https://twitter.com/flybayer/status/1328707093638107138). It's built on Next.js and is designed to abstract away the complexities of an API. It's trying to be the Rails of the JS world.